# Modal com objeto json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

preciso pegar uma imagem por `json` pra aparecer no meu modal porém o modal aparece mas a imagem não

aqui ta meu código

```
$("#estoque1").click(function(){
    $('#estoqueModal').modal('show');
    $(".modal-body").innerHTML += '<img src="' + dadosJSON.estoque.imgModal + '">';
});
```

Comment: Cadê o código da requisição ajax? De onde vem esse dadosJSON.estoque.imgModal? Poderia postar o código da página que será feita a requisição ajax?

Comment: Não estou usando ajax, to fazendo direto do js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já deve ter alternado as linhas né? Se não fez, faça e teste.

Alguns pontos a verificar... Você consegue imprimir a imagem sem ser no modal?
Caso sim, tente carrega-la de forma assíncrona, 

`setTimeout(function(){
  $(".modal-body").innerHTML += '<img src="' + dadosJSON.estoque.imgModal + '">';
}`

Ou coloque no evento "onShow" do modal, veja a documentação do modal que você está usando.